# Python: Why is my If/And/Or statement returning the incorrect result?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm new to Python and am currently in the process of moving a process away from Excel and into Python. I have a scenario where I am trying to query three columns (line by line) in the DataFrame and put the results into a new column called "Within limit by more than one repayment + £12 or less?". I am using Jupyter Notebook (not sure if that helps with anything or not but thought I would mention it anyway), Python version 3.7.6 and Pandas version 1.0.1

The totals that show in Python are out by 5 compared to the existing Excel formula and I cannot fathom out why this is.

For reference, here is the existing Excel formula and totals produced:

```
=IF(AND(OR(AY2="System 1",AY2="Both"),AX2="Under",AZ2<0,AZ2>-13),"Yes","No")
```

Totals:

No = 108,566
Yes = 9,995

Here is the code and results when moved over into Python. I appreciate this may not be the best way to do it - if it isn't the best way, please could someone also suggest/point me in the direction to a better way of doing it?

```
def GreaterThanOneRepaymentPlus12PoundOrLess(df1):
    
    if (df1['Is biggest difference System 1 or System 2?'] == 'System 1' \
        or df1['Is biggest difference System 1 or System 2?'] == 'Both') \
    and (df1['Biggest real diff direction'] == 'Under' \
         and df1['Difference between repayment and amount outstanding'] < 0 \
         and df1['Difference between repayment and amount outstanding'] > -13):
        return 'Yes'
    else:
        return 'No'
    
%time df1['Within limit by more than one repayment + £12 or less?'] = df1.apply(GreaterThanOneRepaymentPlus12PoundOrLess, axis = 1)
```

Totals:

No = 108,571
Yes = 9,990

I'm guessing it will have something to do with how Python interprets/executes "IF" statements compared to Excel but I am stuck as to what could be causing the issue.

Comment: It looks OK to me. A third alternative, which you might have considered, is to use VBA to calculate the value in the Excel spreadsheet. VBA lives inside Excel, and is deployed when you give someone a spreadsheet.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, that always helps a lot when asking these types of questions.